# Android LinearLayout casting in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, fragment, android-linearlayout

I'm working with AFreeChart, i'm trying to display a chart inside a fragment. I've been running around in circles for a while, i've seen a couple of posts that looks similar to my problem but i still cant get my head around it.

This is how my onCreateView() in the fragment class Looks like.

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_market, container, false);

            viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.marketGraphFrame);

            chartView = (ChartView) view; 

            chartView.drawChart(ChartFactory.createBarChart("Headline","Time", "Value", createDataset(),PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false));

            viewGroup.addView(chartView);

    return view;

    }
```

This is the xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="NYSE" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LSE" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OMX" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/marketGraphFrame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group_market"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/candleStickMarket"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonChart"
            android:text="@string/candle_stick" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/barChartMarket"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonChart"
            android:text="@string/bar_chart" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/lineChartMarket"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonChart"
            android:text="@string/line_chart" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group_time_market"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/thirtydays"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonTime"
            android:text="@string/thirty_days" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/oneweek"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonTime"
            android:text="@string/one_week" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/oneday"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonTime"
            android:text="@string/one_day" />
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the main part of the error message.

**java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to com.example.mercbisandroid.ChartView**

please advice.

I got it working with these three lines inside an Activity

```
viewGroup = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.DiaGroup);
chartView = new ChartView(this);
viewGroup.addView(chartView);
```

And the ChartView is declared in the class :

```
ChartView chartView;
```

***I finally managed to get it working. Dont know if its 100% accurate todo it this way but :***

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_market, container, false);

        viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.marketGraph); 

        chartView = new ChartView(getActivity());

        chartView.drawChart(ChartFactory.createBarChart("Headline","Time", "Value", createDataset(), PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false));

        viewGroup.addView(chartView);

return view;

}
```

Comment: The "Root" view of your XML Layout is `LinearLayout`. You should cast it to `LinearLayout` not `ChartView`.

Comment: I'm sure that's the trick or not, there might be something fundamentally wrong with my code which make everythin a bit unclear.

Comment: I don't see you declaring any `ChartView`.. and you are trying to draw a chart..

Comment: Oh my mistake, added the line to the post.

Comment: As you can se the id is changed but that had nothing todo with it. Just something that happened on the way :)